# best way to backup and restore partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-12, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a table with 600 partitions and 68 millions of rows.

I successfully run backup using
`pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -Fc --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres -t "table_employe*" > /backup-nfs/dump_employee_date +\%d-\%m-\%y-\%H\%M\%S.sql`.
The process runs without error. I check periodically after a couple of hours that the size of the backup file not increasing anymore. So I conclude that the `pg_dump` has finished with the final size of **18 GB**.

I restore that file using `pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/replay_backup4 -U postgres < /data/dump_employee_`

The restore finish without error. The DB size is not increasing after some time :
`pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/replay_backup4 -U postgres < /data/dump_employee`,

so I conclude the restoration process has finished.

But, when I check the result, only 7 million rows are inserted. There are 61 million rows missing ! :(

I do another backup, but this time without compression : `pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres -t "table_employe*" > /backup-nfs/dump_employee.sql`.
It results in **119 GB**. But I have not restored this backup yet.

So, how do I back up and restore the partitioned table correctly? And how do I know whether there are differences in the number of rows or not?

Postgres 12; Ubuntu 20.04

Please kindly advice. Many thanks

Comment: You have to wait for the commands to *terminate*. Once that happened, run `pg_restore -l dumpfile` and check if the dump contains everything it should.

Comment: is it this command `pg_stat_activity.application_name` used to monitor the process of `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` ? Or are there ay other commands? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: You should look at the `state`, `wait_event`, `wait_event_type` and `query` columns of the `pg_stat_activity` row where `application_name` is `pg_dump`.